# Android Blood pressure graph implementation?

Tags: android-graphview

Thanks for reading the question, I need to implement the Blood pressure graph in my Android sample application, I attached the sample image below, Can i use third party libraries like achart engine and MPChart Android for making the graph,Any ideas and suggestions kindly share those details,

[image]

Thanks ,
Naren.S

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you http://www.android-graphview.org/ library. It's super easy to use. However I'm not sure how to implement the vertical lines among points since you'd have to introduce two LineGraphSeries.

But if you don't need that vertical lines, the GraphView library would be wise and easy solution :)